# setting a listener on array of of objects

Tags: java, javafx

I have an array of wrapper objects which wrap javafx controls:

- CheckBox
- Spinner

I want to be able to listen to changes on the CheckBox or the Spinner. I have tried extracting the information I need but the problem with this is that it only works if the array has Spinner only.

Some of my code:

```
ObservableList<WrapperClass>  WrapperObjectList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
     new Callback<WrapperClass, Observable[]>() {
          @Override
          public Observable[] call(WrapperClass param) {
               return new Observable[] {
                    ((Spinner) param.getControl()).valueProperty()
                };
          }
     }
);
```

**WrapperClass.java**

```
private Item item;
private Control control;

public WrapperClass(Item item, Control control) {
    this.item = item;
    this.control = control;
}
```

Comment: What's a `NumberField`? Can't you just do an `instanceof` check in the `call()` method?

Comment: @James_D that was an extension of Spinner. I've changed accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fairly naive but straightforward solution would just be to test the type of the wrapped node:

```
ObservableList<WrapperClass>  WrapperObjectList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
     new Callback<WrapperClass, Observable[]>() {
          @Override
          public Observable[] call(WrapperClass param) {
               if (param.getControl() instanceof Spinner) {
                   return new Observable[] {
                       ((Spinner) param.getControl()).valueProperty()
                   };
               } else if (param.getControl() instanceof CheckBox) {
                   return new Observable[] {
                       ((CheckBox) param.getControl()).selectedProperty()
                   };
               } else return new Observable[0] ;
          }
     }
);
```

A more elegant approach would be to expose the appropriate property from the `WrapperClass`. You could make `WrapperClass` abstract:

```
public abstract class WrapperClass {

    private Item item;
    private Control control;

    public WrapperClass(Item item, Control control) {
        this.item = item;
        this.control = control;
    }

    public abstract Observable observableValue() ;

}
```

and then create concrete subclasses:

```
public class SpinnerWrapper extends WrapperClass {

    private final Spinner spinner ;

    public SpinnerWrapper(Item item, Spinner spinner) {
        super(item, spinner);
        this.spinner = spinner ;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable observableValue() {
        return spinner.valueProperty();
    }
}
```

and similarly for `CheckBoxSpinner`. Then you just need

```
ObservableList<WrapperClass>  WrapperObjectList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
     new Callback<WrapperClass, Observable[]>() {
          @Override
          public Observable[] call(WrapperClass param) {
               return new Observable[] {
                    param.observableValue()
                };
          }
     }
);
```

Alternatively, you could make `WrapperClass` generic and supply a function to it that returns the property you need:

```
public class WrapperClass<C extends Control> {

    private Item item ;
    private C control ;

    private Function<C, Observable> valueFunction ;

    public WrapperClass(Item item, C control, Function<C, Observable> valueFunction) { 
        this.item = item ;
        this.control = control ;
        this.valueFunction = valueFunction ;
    }

    public Observable observableValue() {
        return valueFunction.apply(control);
    }
}
```

which you would instantiate as

```
WrapperClass<Spinner> spinnerWrapper = new WrapperClass(someItem, someSpinner, 
    Spinner::valueProperty);
WrapperClass<CheckBox> checkBoxWrapper = new WrapperClass(someOtherItem, someCheckBox, 
    CheckBox::selectedProperty);
```

The observable list would be created with the extractor just returning `param.observableValue()` as above.